# Button onclick jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am trying to get a button class to be clicked and redirected to a new page.

But it is not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
    $('li#menu-item-28').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        //alert('Clicked');
    url = "http://wwww.bbc.co.uk";
        $(location).attr("href", url);
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you are trying to redirect directly in this handler you should write `window.location.href = url`

Comment: It does not work because location is not an element in the DOM

Comment: put single quotes around location, if it is a class put a dot also, if it is an id put #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read this link below:**

[`window.location.href`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBzaW815fUAhWGv48KHb3SDCIQFgg8MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FWindow%2Flocation&usg=AFQjCNHozfeS8jbGqC-qUCMSMbaYDIIrpQ&sig2=gREMRv4R5p18xuykVCeP1Q)

```
 $('li#menu-item-28').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        //alert('Clicked');
    window.location.href = "http://www.bbc.co.uk";

    });
```

Comment: You got a typo.

Comment: windoe.location.href = "http://wwww.bbc.co.uk";
 should be:  window.location.href = "http://wwww.bbc.co.uk";

Comment: Hey Prasad, just edited this.  Thanks for the solution mate. I will mark as the answer.  Cheers for the help have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

try window.location.href = url;

```
$(document).on('click','li#menu-item-28',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk";
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: Hey Dinesh  - thanks for this but this doesn't work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

if your element generate dynamically , you should listen on document :

```
$(document).on('click','li#menu-item-28',function(){
      url = "http://wwww.bbc.co.uk";
       window.location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
url = "http://wwww.bbc.co.uk";
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

works for me